# Joomla plugin get contents of whole page before output

Tags: php, joomla, output

With my Joomla plugin I would like to get and modify all the contents before the output is created.

```
function newContent($html)
    {
    $html = "new content";
    return $html;
    }

function onContentPrepare()
    {
    ob_start(array($this, "newContent"));
    return true;
    }

function onContentBeforeDisplay()
    {
    ob_end_flush();
    return true;
    }
```

I tried with `onContentAfterDisplay` but it continues to change only a small piece and not all the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't you just do:

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
{
     $article->text = "new content";
}
```

?

**EDIT**

Basing on your response, here is a way to modify whole page content/body in plugin. Add this method to your plugin:

```
public function onAfterRender()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $currentBodyToChange = $app->getBody();

    //do something with $currentBodyToChange
    //$bodyChanged is modified $currentBodyToChange

    $app->setBody($bodyChanged);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i would like to get and modify all the contents (head, body, footer), all the page, not only the article

Comment: @arbogast this works smoothly if you have single article on the page but if you have another component or even "Featured Articles" onAfterRender doesn't fire. Do you know if there's a way to do this on any page? Another weird thing I noticed - on Admin side it fires every time.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a plugin firing on the admin pages...

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if ($app->isSite())  echo 'Front end - do it!';
if ($app->isAdmin()) echo 'Admin pages - ignore!';
```